# Swapping windows in split-screen mode

Tags: android-12, multi-window

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. I would like to ask, how do I swap the above window with the below in split-screen mode?

For instance, I may have an app I am typing into above and music from YouTube below, and I want to switch the app I am typing in without stopping the music. But when I hit the three-line apps button, it is the window below (YouTube) that is minimized, and the music stops.

Instead, I want to be able to swap above and below, so that YouTube goes at the top and the app I am typing into (e.g. Google Keep) goes below, so that I am able to hit the square button and bring up Google Chrome after navigating to the Google Chrome app icon on the navigation screen where it is fine, for instance.

I could have opened YouTube first and then selected split window to open Keep or Chrome after that, but in general, navigation flow can require apps to be opened up in any order. So, I would rather be able to swap the app at the top with the one at the bottom in multi window, to achieve my end.

One possible way this could be done is to press the three-dot divider, drag, and then click on one of the app icons on either the top or bottom part of the screen before they disappear after the three-dot divider is released, but this does not work.

How can I swap the top and bottom windows in split-screen mode?

Comment: *In split screen you can change the ratio of these apps using that split-line by moving it up & down and you can exchange the position of these apps also, to do so you just have to tap on that split-line bar and here you have two options first is for the same that is exchange the position of these split screen apps and second is the cross icon to close the below one as shown in the GIF*(https://c.realme.com/in/post-details/1344344280830836736) may help

Comment: I can follow your instructions to swap windows, but I don't see the second option to close one window. I usually do this by dragging the split three dot divider to the edge of the phone. If there another way? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how it works on your Realme OS and only pointed out a source from Internet