# Android 13: Swapping apps in split screen and adding new apps

Tags: android-13, multi-window, google-pixel-6a

*Not a duplicate of [Swapping windows in split-screen mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253087/swapping-windows-in-split-screen-mode) since it is Android 12 specific (I actually wrote out an answer for this without realizing the question is for Android 12 and instead of wasting the efforts in answering, I decided to make it a self-answered question).*

**As in title, how do I switch apps from top pane to bottom pane (and vice-versa) as also add a new app?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Firstly, the behavior of split panel has changed from earlier behavior. See the open issue tracker of Dec 21 (before Android 12 L update) [Split screen feature doesn't work as it use to](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210345474).
- This works on Android 13, Pixel 6a, YMMV depending on the customization of your OEM.

I used split screen to pin two apps *Permission Manager X* on the top pane and *What's running pro*  on the bottom pane (app *selected first* for split screen goes into top panel).

[image]

## To switch panels

**Double tap** on the panel divider

[image]

## To change one of the panels

For example you want to change the top panel, close the app on the top panel and add a new app which *automatically* occupies the top panel.

And of course, double tap the panel divider if you want to switch panels.

[image]

Comment: I just tested this on Pixel 3a, Android 12L, and this answer worked. Unfortunately, I don't have Android 12 to test.

Comment: @AndrewT thanks. As mentioned in the first point this behavior is valid since 12L. Both my devices 4a and 6a are on 13, so I too can't test it on 12. Maybe somebody can!

Comment: Can you please explain how to change only one panel a bit better?